# Django filter two records and update both at once?

Tags: django

I need to filter two data's and then update each data with different value ! How to do that at once ?

```
x = Tasks.objects.filter(employee=[person1]) 
y = Tasks.objects.filter(employee=[person2])
```

Basically am updating count, for instance lets say i have a model named "Employee" and he is assigned to tasks with model named "Task". And whenever admin adds employees to a task - the employee gets to see the count of total task.

With this said, i have managed to update the count by "1" when tasks gets added and managed to updated the count by "-1" when its get deleted, but my problem is when tasks gets updated or edited or assigned to another employee !

Now am updating the task using:

```
x.update(total_task=F('total_task') + 1) and again 
y.update(total_task=F('total_task') - 1)
```

From the above, first i filter each separately and then update separately ! How to combine this in a single query ?

```
Task Model:

class Task(models.Model):
    employee= models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    total_task = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

class Employee(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=128)
    ............
    .......
```

Comment: For you first query that filter your results you may try something as following : query = Tasks.objects.filter(employee__in=[person1, person2])

Comment: Okay how to update both with different values ? as +1 and -1 ? @em1le

Comment: Or it might be better to just add a model property that counts the task when you need it. That way you won't have to maintain the values yourself

Comment: How to do that ? any examples @BrianD

Comment: Can you share all the related models?

Comment: Have made edits @BrianD

Comment: Why do you want to put them in one query? It seems you are concerned about atomicity? See the documentation on [Database transactions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/transactions/).